# How to update a field in an array element with another field in the same element?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const holderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        walletId: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        solBalance: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
            min: 0,
        },
        liquidityPools: [
            {
                collectionId: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    required: true,
                },
                lpTokens: {
                    type: Number,
                    required: true,
                    min: 0,
                },
                feeEarned: {
                    type: Number,
                    default: 0,
                    min: 0,
                },
                isActive: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

export default mongoose.models.Holder || mongoose.model('Holder', holderSchema)
```

In this model how can I do something like this -
liquidityPools.feeEarned += liquidityPools.lpTokens /100 for array elements of all docs with liquidityPools.collectionId as 5

```
await Holder.updateMany(
                        { 'liquidityPools.collectionId': collectionId, 'liquidityPools.isActive': true },
                        {
                            $inc: {
                                'liquidityPools.$[elem].feeEarned': {
                                    $multiply: [
                                        'elem.lpTokens',100
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        }
                    )
                 })`
```

This is what I tried but using $multiple inside $inc doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update MongoDB documents using the aggregation pipeline ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)).

Here is how the query might look like:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "liquidityPools.collectionId": "60d1a0a0fd92f81b8e7a1dc1",
  "liquidityPools.isActive": true
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      liquidityPools: {
        $map: {
          input: "$liquidityPools",
          as: "pool",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$pool.collectionId",
                  "60d1a0a0fd92f81b8e7a1dc1"
                ]
              },
              {
                collectionId: "$$pool.collectionId",
                lpTokens: "$$pool.lpTokens",
                feeEarned: {
                  $add: [
                    "$$pool.feeEarned",
                    {
                      $multiply: [
                        "$$pool.lpTokens",
                        100
                      ]
                    },
                    
                  ],
                  
                },
                isActive: "$$pool.isActive",
                
              },
              "$$pool",
              
            ],
            
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

Here is MongoDB playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jdkxXlHlgEx) to see the query work.